# Ruby on Rails locales in .rb extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

Taken from the rails guide:

*You may use YAML (.yml) or plain Ruby (.rb) files for storing your translations in SimpleStore. YAML is the preferred option among Rails developers. However, it has one big disadvantage. YAML is very sensitive to whitespace and special characters, so the application may not load your dictionary properly.*

Im trying to load my i18n locale files in a .rb files since the spanish accents in the .yml file end up throwing a I18n::InvalidLocaleData error.

However Ive tried copy pasting the file into a .rb and it doesnt work. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Can you please do the following to flesh out your question: 1) Provide an example of the YAML that was throwing the error (plenty of people successfully use accents in i18n YAML files, so yours may be a special case) and 2) provide an example of how you moved the code from the YAML file to the Ruby file (did you *literally* copy-paste the code from YAML to Ruby?).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to do it like this:

```rb
{ de: {
errors: {
  messages: {
  restrict_dependent_destroy: {
    one: "Datensatz kann nicht gelöscht werden, da ein abhängiger %{record}-Datensatz existiert.",
    many: "Datensatz kann nicht gelöscht werden, da abhängige %{record} existieren." }}}}}
```

Where `%{record}` would be [interpolated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation).